# Can Electron affect other OS apps?

Tags: operating-system, electron

I'm thinking of making a text expanding app with Electron. Is it even possible to make an Electron app that can do that? For instance, if the Electron app is open and I enter an abbreviation into Sublime Text and hit tab will it expand?

Comment: Just the one electron?  The probability is finite, but vanishingly small and unknowable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron allows you to make apps that run node scripts and display UI in a webkit based view.

The purpose of Electron is to provide native OS interactions to node and package everything in a distributable app. It does a fairly decent job covering basic OS interaction, however it is by no means a full API wrapper.

In short, no Electron itself will not do this. I doubt it is worth the time writing a node module for this purpose, you would be far better off writing a native app for whatever platform you are targeting.

Comment: Thanks. What about https://github.com/ptmt/react-native-desktop ? It looks like legit native stuff.

Comment: It may be closer.. I have no experience with react native.

Comment: Actually, React and Electron are probably stupid for this. It doesn't need an interface at all. I'll try to figure out how to write a simple native app for osx. :)

Comment: Ah, OS X. My knowledge of the Cocoa API is a little rusty but I can offer some search terms for you: Cocoa, NSEvents, Quartz Events.

Comment: Appreciate it. I think I'm gonna go with Swift. Seems like he simple/clean/easy/modern way to dev anything on Apple.